# QSortFilterProxyModel and columnCount

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt, proxy, qt4

I have 2 models:
`MyModel`  (`inherits QAbstractItemModel`, its tree) and `MyProxyModel` (`inherits QSortFilterProxyModel`).

Column count of MyModel is 1, and items in MyModel contain information which should be showed in QTableView using MyProxyModel. I used MyProxyModel with `MyProxyModel::columnCount() == 5`.

I overloaded function `MyProxyModel::data()`. But table view shows only data from column 1(`MyModel::columnCount`).

After debugging I found that `MyProxyModel::data()` gets only indexes with `column < MyModel::columnCount()` (It seems that it uses `MyModel::columnCount()` and ignores `MyProxyModel::columnCount()`).

In the table view header sections count is equal to `MyProxyModel::columnCount()` (It's OK ;)).

How can I show information in cells with `column > MyModel::columnCount()`?

**MyModel.cpp:**

```
int MyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    return 1;
}
```

**MyProxyModel.cpp:**

```
int MyProxyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    return 5;
}

QVariant MyProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    const int  r = index.row(),
                  c = index.column();
    QModelIndex itemIndex = itemIndex = this->index(r, 0, index.parent());
    itemIndex = mapToSource(itemIndex);
    MyModel model = dynamic_cast<ItemsModel*>(sourceModel());
    Item* item = model->getItem(itemIndex);
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
          if(c == 0)
          {
                return model->data(itemIndex, role);
          }
          return item->infoForColumn(c);
    }
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::data(index, role)
}
```

Comment: Show us some code. Show us how did you reimplement columnCount in proxy model. Show us how did you setup proxy model on view

Comment: Show us all the `const` keywords in your code. So far data won't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Krzysztof Ciebiera had said, in not as many words: your `data` and `columnCount` methods are never called, because they are not declared correctly. The virtual methods you're supposed to implement have the signatures

```
int columnCount(const QModelIndex&) const;
QVariant data(const QModelIndex&, int) const;
```

while your methods have differing signatures

```
int columnCount(QModelIndex&) const;
QVariant data(QModelIndex&, int);
```

and thus they won't get called. Notice that your methods incorrectly expect a non-const reference to a model index. Your `data()` method also expects non-const object instance.

Comment: I added missed const-es in question description(in real code I use missed here const keyword).